# Can I use JavaScript to pass an email to a python file I have in my website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am using Django for my website and so am more familiar with Python. Because of this I want to send an email to an email address I receive from my HTML and JS form using Python not JavaScript, as I know little JS. Any ideas/suggestions? What is the JS code to use for sending data from a JS program to a Python script? WITHOUT using Ajax or extra content.
Is there a way to just do it using plain JS???

Comment: Look at using Ajax

Comment: What is the duplicate?

Comment: I think what you want to ask is how do you send data from the website using JS to your backend service written in Python, or so I assume, for that take a look at fetch API of Javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API , also please read JS documentation, as you'll soon run into issues like promises and callbacks, that are not so easy to understand. MDN is a good place for that too!

Comment: This is not a duplicate, if reading my question I state without using Ajax or extra content!!!

Comment: @ishaan thanks but not what I am looking for.